# Migration room database, alter table, android?

Tags: android, sqlite, migration, android-room

In my app I am using ROOM db to save some data.

I have table UserInfo with some columns in version 1.

Later I added an integer column to the database, I upgraded the database version, added the migration code but I am getting this below exception

```
Migration didn't properly handle UserInfo(ima.rvtech.model.api.result.UserInfo).
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='UserInfo', columns={
address=Column{name='address', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
password=Column{name='password', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
actBy=Column{name='actBy', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
emailId=Column{name='emailId', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
userType=Column{name='userType', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
pinCode=Column{name='pinCode', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
uploadImagePath=Column{name='uploadImagePath', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
loginId=Column{name='loginId', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
actDate=Column{name='actDate', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
contactNo=Column{name='contactNo', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
uploadVideoPath=Column{name='uploadVideoPath', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
edbNo=Column{name='edbNo', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, 
emergencyContactNo=Column{name='emergencyContactNo', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
bannerImagePath=Column{name='bannerImagePath', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
MyFriendListCount=Column{name='MyFriendListCount', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
userName=Column{name='userName', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
operationType=Column{name='operationType', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='UserInfo', columns={
address=Column{name='address', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
 password=Column{name='password', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
actBy=Column{name='actBy', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
emailId=Column{name='emailId', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
userType=Column{name='userType', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
pinCode=Column{name='pinCode', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
 uploadImagePath=Column{name='uploadImagePath', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
loginId=Column{name='loginId', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
actDate=Column{name='actDate', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
contactNo=Column{name='contactNo', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
uploadVideoPath=Column{name='uploadVideoPath', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
edbNo=Column{name='edbNo', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, 
emergencyContactNo=Column{name='emergencyContactNo', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
bannerImagePath=Column{name='bannerImagePath', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
MyFriendListCount=Column{name='MyFriendListCount', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
userName=Column{name='userName', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
operationType=Column{name='operationType', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

I am adding an integer column in next version `MyFriendListCount`

Below is my migration code

```
public static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE UserInfo "
                + " ADD COLUMN MyFriendListCount INTEGER");
    }
};
```

Can some one point me what piece of code I am missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got help from Mike's solution to help me understand, 
While you are going for NOT NULL you also need to set default value to column

```
public static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE UserInfo "
                + " ADD COLUMN MyFriendListCount INTEGER default 0 NOT NULL");

    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
For version from 2 to 3    

 val MIGRATION_2_3 = object : Migration(2, 3) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            //Integer values
            database.execSQL(
                "ALTER TABLE ProjectListingResponse "
                        + " ADD COLUMN dummy INTEGER default 0 NOT NULL"
            );
            //String values
            database.execSQL(
                "ALTER TABLE ProjectListingResponse "
                        + " ADD COLUMN dummy2 TEXT default 0 NOT NULL"
            );
        }
    }

  Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java,DATABASE_NAME)
                       // .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()         //will delete all existing data from device and update new schema
                       .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2, MIGRATION_2_3)  //Only update the schema much recomonded
                        .build()
```

Answer (score 1):

Room is expecting  :-

```
MyFriendListCount=Column{name='MyFriendListCount', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
```

You've provided :-

```
MyFriendListCount=Column{name='MyFriendListCount', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
```

I believe you need to add the **NOT NULL** constraint, so perhaps use :-

```
public static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE UserInfo "
                + " ADD COLUMN MyFriendListCount INTEGER NOT NULL");
    }
};
```

Comment: I get this exception after adding the above code "Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE UserInfo  ADD COLUMN MyFriendListCount INTEGER NOT NULL"